# Do "map" and "cat" rhyme?

Tags: vowels, rhymes

**Do the words *map* and *cat* rhyme?**

I'm of the opinion that they do because—even though they end with different sounds—the vowel sound is the same.

Please help settle a debate between my children and me.

Comment: The kids are almost certainly being taught in school that the words don't rhyme, regardless of any nuanced answer given below.

Comment: /p/ and /t/ are similar sounds, but in your opinion does *map* rhyme with *cash*, *stamp*, *pacts* and/or *cab*? It's not clear why you think *map* and *cat* rhyme, maybe you are unable to differentiate /p/ and /t/ (both can be pronounced as a glottal stop in some dialects).

Comment: The classic study is Zwicky, 1976, ["Well, this rock-and-roll has got to stop: Junior's head is hard as a rock"](https://web.stanford.edu/~zwicky/this-rock-and-roll.pdf).

Comment: @jimm101 you mean "based on the reasoning used by the nuanced answer given below"?

Comment: [everything rhymes if you are eminemy enough](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_kQBVneC30o)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It depends what meaning of *rhyme* you choose.

The OED has a note attached to its definition of "rhyme":

> Rhyme, strictly speaking, is regarded as extending to the last
> stressed vowel and any sounds following it, whether within one word or
> more than one, in patterns such as female, feminine, male, masculine,
> rich, tailed rhyme, etc.; however, use of the word frequently includes
> various kinds of partial correspondence, as eye-, near-, off-,
> slant-rhyme, etc.: for these terms see the first element.The term is
> sometimes extended to include assonance and even alliteration (initial
> or head rhyme).

So no, they do not rhyme "strictly speaking", but the word is sometimes used more loosely.

Comment: I think this answer reads a little too much leeway into the OED definition. The OED does not merely exclude assonance from the strict definition (as the rest of the answer suggests), but explicitly labels use of the word for assonance an _extension_. That suggests the OED consider such use less valid than merely a "loose" usage (which would be the eye-, near-, off-, and slant-rhymes they mention earlier). The OED exclude it from rhyme not only sensu stricto, but also sensu lato, allowing it only sensu latissimo - in the broadest sense

Comment: it is also worth stating explicitly that in school the children are likely being taught, and expected to use the word, in one of it's stricter senses (possibly allowing rhymes just of the last syllable, rather than from the last stressed syllable)

Comment: In one of his books, Stephen Sondheim decried "near rhymes" as lazy lyric writing.

Comment: @Barmar Any "rhymes" other than true rhymes are almost universally frowned on in musical theatre writing (Sondheim’s genre, for any who don’t know), but in pop, rock, etc., clever half rhymes are often appreciated, or at least accepted.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Yeah, but there's a tremendous pop influence on modern musical theatre (not even including rock operas and productions based on the library of pop superstars).

Comment: So nothing rhymes with orange. Except Stonehenge, revenge, and [blorange](https://www.dictionary.com/e/fashion/blorange/).

Answer (score 58):

Map and cat do not rhyme but they have assonance.

> **assonance** n.
>
> **2.a.** Prosody. **The correspondence or rhyming of one word with another in the accented vowel and those which follow, but not in the consonants,** as used in the versification of Old French, Spanish, Celtic, and other languages.
>
> 1861   F. A. March Eng. Lang. (1862) 403   T*he rule of assonance..requires the repetition of the same vowels in the assonant words, from the last accented vowel inclusive. Thus man and hat, nation and traitor, penitent and reticence, are assonant couples of words.*

Comment: cool new word, thanks

Comment: These days we may think of poetry mostly in terms of rhyme (which can be seen as a specific type of assonance), but assonance generally has been important in poetry too; the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assonance) gives many examples.

Comment: "[Assonance means getting the rhyme wrong](https://www.litcharts.com/lit/educating-rita/act-two-scene-three)"

Comment: @gidds What, no love for alliteration as an organizing principle?

Comment: @user888379 :) alliteration is different: OED: The occurrence of the same letter or sound at the beginning of adjacent or closely connected words, - 1933   Amer. Speech 8 i. 22/2   *The socialists climbed on the alliteration band-wagon with Sail safely and surely with Socialism.*

Comment: @user888379 I was going to mention alliteration too, but you then have to mention consonance too — of which alliteration is a subtype, just as rhyme is a subtype of assonance, but that needs further links, and by then the comment was getting unmanageable so I edited it out :-)

Comment: @Greybeard I was alluding more specifically to alliteration as a building block of poetry (particularly older forms).

Comment: In Romance languages, **both *assonant rhyme* and *consonant rhyme* are considered rhymes**: [see here](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rima). Of those two, assonant rhyme is by far the more common because it is easier to make with their words. *Alliteration* is sometimes called *head rhyme* in Germanic poetry, but it is not the same thing as what consonant rhyme means in Romance, which is a kind of *tail rhyme*. There’s also a distinction between single-syllabled *masculine rhyme* and many-syllabled *feminine rhyme*, where the feminine rhyme is the rarer of the two because it is so much harder.

Comment: I wish I could remember where I saw a web page about sonnets, which suggested that beyond the ABAB rhyme scheme within each quatrain, there was an AABB pattern of stresses: "Shall I comPARE the to a SUMmer's day.  Thou art more LOVEly and more TEMperate.  Harsh WINDS do SHAKE the darling buds of MAY, and SUMmer's BREEZE hath all too short a DATE".  Yet another way in which lines of poetry can be sonically related to each other.